# how to construct a function which is $C^k$ but not $C^{k+1}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have done this for $k=0,1$ like $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$, which is $C^0$ but not $C^1$, then $g(x)=\int_{0}^{x}t^{\frac13} dt$ is $C^1$ but not $C^2$, could any one tell me how to generalize this?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried just doing the same thing again?

Comment: meaning?I do not understand your statement

Comment: You should iterate your process. Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous but not differentiable. Then $G=\int_0^t g(s) ds$ is $C^1$ but not $C^2$. Now do the same with $G$. It's primitive is $C^2$ but not $C^3$ and so on

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh Idiot! (myself)

Answer (score 7):

$g_k(x)=x^{(3k+1)/3}$ is $C^k$ but not $C^{k+1}$. Or you could repeat the same idea, with $\int_0^x g(s)\,ds$ being $C^2$ but not $C^3$, and so on.